# How do you create a new version of an app for testing with updates (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm fairly new to app development, and I just recently put my first app in the App Store. I noticed some bugs after it was released, and when I tried to test it, it overwrote the version I had downloaded from the app store. I have the app connected to Game Center, so I want to avoid setting a high score while I am testing. Normally, in the test version I am logged out, and it has my ID saved for the App Store version, so it auto logs in for that version. However now that the new version has been overwritten, I can't login at all.

How do I keep them separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bundle id like com.company.game to com.company.game2 or so

Comment: Would I then have to change it back when I submit the update?

Comment: Yes, exactly you need to change it back before submitting it.